# clang++ compiles an executable, but clang-check cannot find std header

Tags: cmake, clang-static-analyzer

I have a test cmake C++ app, that I can compile successfully with clang++-10 on Ubuntu 20.04 (with all that CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE machinery).

The layout of the cmake project is:

```
./test.cpp
./CMakeLists.txt
./build
```

I also create the build database json file with CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS inside ./build (this json file is necessary for the clang-check operation AFAIU).

Now, launched from the build dir, the check invocation fails:

```
clang-check-10 --analyze  ../test.cpp
<projDir>/test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
     ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Error while processing <projDir>/test.cpp.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Edit:** Have also tried specifying `-p=$(pwd)` to clang-check, but it still could not find the header.

Comment: To improve this question, I suggest adding the contents of `test.cpp`, `CMakeLists.txt`, and the exact commands you use to build.  Then others can easily reproduce the scenario to try to solve the problem.  Furthermore, that way people encountering similar errors with their own code can compare to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

clang-check is not a compiler. It's used for checking error in AST, and in this case it can't find the system header in your code. Add '--' in the end of line to ignore it.

```
clang-check-10 --analyze  ../test.cpp
```

For more information: [ClangCheck on LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCheck.html)